# Editing incorrect answer on duplicate

Tags: discussion, new-users

I came across [this](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/66035/why-is-it-die-neunziger-and-not-die-neunzigen) post today and I'm a bit confused, I'm fairly new on SE in general, the question itself has been marked as a duplicate, but an answer was provided before it was marked which is just plainly incorrect

What is the proper action in this sort of case? Should I edit the answer? Flag it? Ignore it so it vanishes as a duplicate?

Comment: Regarding the answer you can handle it like any other answer you consider incorrect: Downvote and leave a comment why you think it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Answers can't be marked as duplicate, and according to my knowledge there is no need to do anything at all.

The link to the duplicate is visible on the right hand side ("Linked") on both questions and sometimes the questions while closely related are not fully identical, so having the answers separate is helpful.

While in principle moderators may chose to merge questions it is seldom done due to the effort involved to get this cleanly resolved.